# UIView animation doesn't work for UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I try to add a subview(which is a subclassed UIViewController's view, consists of several UIButtons and UILabels) to current view, but the animation doesn't work, the subview just appeared without animation.

the code is :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimaitonCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:thisPersonViewController.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubView:thisPersonViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

it just doesn't work, but if I change **forView** parameter from **the subview** (thisPersonViewController.view) to **self.view**, the self.view did animate, that's curios.

My xcode version is 4.2 and SDK version is 5.0, thx for anyone who offer an solution!

===========THE FOLLOWING CODE WORKS FINE===============

```
CATransition *trans = [CATransition animation];
[trans setDuration:0.4f];
[trans setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[trans setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[thisPersonViewController.view layer]addAnimation:trans forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.view addSubview:thisPersonViewController.view];
```

Another annoying question is if I change the CATransition type to **kCATransitionFromBottom** or something else the animation doesn't work again !

Comment: sorry, but this makes no sense at all. please study the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) pattern carefully

Comment: to give you an hint: a view can't be a subclass of a viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add thisPersonViewController.view as a subview with a position somewhere off the screen. (i.e. frame x/y coordinate right at the bottom of the screen.)
2. Do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^(void)
{
    // Move it to wherever you want to have it.
    thisPersonViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, thisPersonViewController.view.frame.size.width, thisPersonViewController.view.frame.size.height);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    // Do something when it completes the animation if you so desire.
}];
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I perform different type of animation , such as UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp ?